# How can I remove [save?, overwrite?, keep CSV format? prompts] while saving .CSV file?

Tags: vba

In general the problem I have is that whenever my code comes to an end (see below) it:

- Asks whether or not to save changes to .csv
  When I click "Yes", it opens the window with location of the file, where I have to select "Save"
- Asks whether or not to overwrite the file
- Asks whether or not to maintain CSV format

Can you advise how can I remove above prompts [simultaneously having this file saved/overwriting the old version]?

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

****rest of the code***

   WB1.Save
   WB2.Save
   WB3.Save
   Application.Quit

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can prevent some of the unneccessary prompts by using the statement `WB2.Saved = True` before you do 'Application.Quit'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @Peter_Pesch , the resolution is as follows [PS. I have 4 files open at the time when VBA is running]:

```
   ....

   WB1.Save
   WB1.Saved = True
   WB2.Saved = True
   WB3.Saved = True
   ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
   Application.Quit

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```